# Degenerate Gaussian Random Variable

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, uniform-convergence

This question is from Hogg, McKean and Craig's book titled "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics."

**3.4.19.** Let the random variable $X$ be $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. What would this distribution be if $\sigma^2 = 0$?
Hint: Look at the mgf of $X$ for $\sigma^2 > 0$ and investigate its limit as $\sigma^2 \to 0$.

**My Thought Process:** Following the hint leads us to an MGF $M_X(t)$ equal to $e^{(\mu t+2 \sigma^2 t^2)}\rvert_{\sigma^2 = 0} = e^{\mu t} $ assuming the pdf has the form $$f(x) = \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}\sigma}e^{\left\{- \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2 \right\}},$$ for $ −\infty < x < \infty.$

The question is that by taking the limit $M_X(t) = E(e^{tX})|_{\sigma^2 \to 0}$ and declaring that the resulting mgf is that of the Gaussian RV when $\sigma^2 = 0$, are we not assuming that the limit and the integral can be interchanged?

Please correct me if I am wrong but $f(x)$ does not converge uniformly to the so called dirac-delta function $\delta(x)$, the characterization of which is pointed out [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/233841/183497). So just because the limit of mgf exists does not mean that it corresponds to the pdf of a "degenerate Gaussian RV". I think that for Gaussian RV, the variance has to necessarily be greater than $0$. In other words, I feel that the question is not correct when looked at from a rigorous point of view.

There are threads where people have mentioned that it corresponds to distributions where probability of $X \neq \mu$ is $0$ ie $X = \mu$ almost surely. But that is besides the point. The question asks for the ***limit*** of a Gaussian RV as variance approaches $0$ and I think that such a distribution cannot exist.

Another issue with this approach of taking limit of mgf as variance approaches zero is that of the right continuity of the cdf (let's call it $F(x)$). The value of $F(x)$ at $x=\mu$ is $0.5$ but when you take the limit $\sigma^2 \to 0$, it poses a problem as we now need $F(\mu) = 1$ for right continuity of cdf. As pointed out [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/116625/183497) in the comments by Dilip, right continuity is an issue.

All I want to know is that am I right in thinking that no such "limit" exists for a Gaussian RV as the variance approaches $0$ and that the question is not correct when looked at with a lens of mathematical rigor?

Please provide feedback and critique my thought process.

Comment: So for centered Gaussian, we have $M_{\sigma}(t) = e^{t^2\sigma^2/2}$. As $\sigma \to 0$, we have convergence to $e^{0} = 1$, which is the MGF of a random variable 0 almost surely. Hence letting $X_n \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2/n)$ we have $X_n \Rightarrow 0$. I don't see any issue with this argument. Perhaps you can clarify what you think is problematic?

Comment: @AndrewZhang $X = 0$ a.s. is fine. That is not my question. The question is about limit of Gaussian RV when variance is $0$. If you take the limit of Gaussian pdf as variance approaches $0$, does it lead to anything meaningful? If so, what is it? Does it lead to a meaningful pdf and cdf that satisfy the requirements of being a pdf and a cdf (like right continuity of cdf etc)?

Comment: Why  are you looking at convergence of cdf's? That is where you are going wrong.

Comment: @geetha290krm Because the question asks what is $N(\mu,0)$ ie what is a normal random variable when the variance is identically equal to $0$. That it results in some distribution which is equal to $\mu$ almost surely is not being contested. What I am contesting is that you cannot plug in $\sigma^2 = 0$ for a normal random variable.

Comment: 1) Convergence in distribution means that convergence of the distribution function happens at all points of continuity of the limiting distribution function. A distribution function of a point mass is not continuous at said point, so convergence is not needed at said point, and there is no issue here. 2) Convergence of densities and its relationship to convergence in distribution is subtle. See perhaps Scheffe's lemma, this implies convergence in total variation.

Comment: You are certainly right in saying that $N(0,1)$ density is not defined when $\sigma=0$. They are using  a vague language and they really want to look at the limiting distribution when $\sigma \to 0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you! That is all I wanted to hear. The question should have been that "by taking the limit of mgf of a Gaussian RV as variance approaches $0$, comment on the distribution whose mgf resembles this limit". Can you please add these comments as part of your answer?

Comment: @AndrewZhang Yes Andrew. As you have mentioned in your second point, the issue really is about setting variance equal to $0$ for a Gaussian RV as suggested in the problem statement. I feel that they need to re-word it so that there is no scope for such errors.

Comment: I fully agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

For convergence in distribution it is not necessary for densities to converge.

If $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$ and $Y=\mu$ then $P(|X-Y|>\epsilon) \leq \frac {\sigma^{2}} {\epsilon^{2}} \to 0$ as $ \sigma \to 0$. Hence, $X$ does converge to $Y$ in probability and this also implies convergence in distribution.